# В RecyclerView криво масштабируются изображения

Tags: java, android, изображения, recyclerview

В RecyclerView ,макет которого состоит из текста + изображения некоторые ImageView криво располагаются. Как я понял, это связано с RecyclerView, т.к. при использовании ListView подобных проблем не возникало. Вот код активности:

```
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class vrasd2 extends AppCompatActivity {
    ArrayList<Phone> phones = new ArrayList<>();
    String stre[] = {"Средняя общеобразовательная школа № 60 распахнула свои двери в 1976 году. Строительство новой школы началось в 1974 году. Заказчиком столь важного объекта социальной инфраструктуры выступил Уфимский моторостроительный завод, директором которого в этот период был Герой Социалистического Труда Михаил Алексеевич Ферин (1907 – 1979). Лето 1976 года выдалось у строителей особенно «жарким»: возводить школу помогали ее будущие учителя и ученики.\n" +
            "5 сентября 1976 г. состоялся торжественный митинг с участием строителей данного объекта. Первый директор Вениамин Иванович Корзников получил символический ключ от школы, а учащиеся дали клятву беречь, хранить и содержать школу в отличном состоянии.","По меркам того времени, школа представляла собой полностью отвечающий всем требованиям инновационный образовательный центр. Новая школа с радостью была встречена жителями микрорайона, ведь их детям приходилось учиться в школе № 51 в три смены.\n" + "Первый директор Вениамин Иванович Корзников (ученики знали его как Виктора Ивановича) родился в крестьянской семье, до войны работал станочником на заводе. В годы Великой Отечественной войны он служил на кораблях Амурской Краснознаменной флотилии на Дальнем Востоке, участвовал в боях с японцами в Маньчжурии.\n" +
            "Работать в школу пришел в 1953 году после окончания педагогического института учителем математики и физики. Вениамин Иванович проработал директором школы с 1976 по 1985 гг. Тысячи учеников и десятки учителей с благодарностью вспоминают требовательного, справедливого, умного и доброго директора. Про первого директора говорили, что у него «На первом месте школа, на втором – школа, на третьем – школа». За отлично построенную систему работы он неоднократно награждался почетными грамотами, ему присвоены звания «Заслуженный учитель Республики Башкортостан» и «Отличник просвещения Российской Федерации».","Первыми заместителями директора по учебно-воспитательной работе стали Тамара Петровна Пайкина и Тамара Дмитриевна Старцева, которые вложили много сил и знаний в создание крепкого и творческого коллектива.\n" +
            "Лицей, ОАО «Уфимское моторостроительное производственное объединение» и Уфимский государственный авиационный технический университет объединяют давние, особые и очень теплые взаимоотношения. С 1986 года в стенах нашего лицея созданы группы с углубленным изучением авиаконструирования, затем ставшие знаменитыми Авиационными классами. Интересно отметить, что учащиеся лицея уже в 1980-е годы сдавали вступительные экзамены в Уфимский государственный авиационный технический университет в стенах родной школы и выпускной бал встречали студентами. Наряду с обычными школьными дисциплинами под руководством преподавателей ВУЗа наши учащиеся изучали предметы «Основы автоматики», «Двигатели летательных аппаратов», «История авиации», «Основы авиаконструирования».","В 1993 году между школой и Уфимским государственным нефтяным техническим университетом был заключен договор об открытии класса с изучением специальностей, связанных с нефтедобывающей и нефтеперерабатывающей промышленностью.\n" +
            "За достигнутые серьезные успехи в обучении и воспитании подрастающего поколения школе в 1997 году присвоен статус школы-лицея, а в 1999 году статус лицея.","За долгие годы плодотворной работы в лицее создался крепкий работоспособный коллектив. В лицее обучается более 1200 учащихся, работает более 80 педагогов, 20 человек технического персонала. Лицей всегда славился своей фундаментальной подготовкой, что проявляется в самых разнообразных сферах. Мы – всегда победители и призеры в районных, городских и республиканских олимпиадах, конкурсах. Славу лицея куют его обучающиеся. Как только рухнул «железный занавес», лицей выходит на международную образовательную арену. В 1990 – 2000-е годы лицеисты побеждали в международных олимпиадах в Италии, Греции, Болгарии, Турции, Польше и других странах.\n" +
            "Лицей гордится, что среди его выпускников ученые, инженеры, врачи, учителя, юристы, военные, журналисты, работники телевидения и т.д. Более 95% выпускников лицея поступают в ведущие ВУЗы Республики Башкортостан и Российской Федерации."};
    int imag[] = {R.drawable.a,R.drawable.b,R.drawable.c,R.drawable.d,R.drawable.e};
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_vrasd2);
        setInitialData();
        RecyclerView recyclerView = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.rv);
        DataAdapter adapter = new DataAdapter(this, phones);
        recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);

    }

    private void setInitialData(){
        for (int i = 0; i < imag.length; i++) {
            phones.add(new Phone (stre[i],imag[i]));
        }

    }
}
```

Разметка:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/txt123"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:textColor="#000"
        android:textSize="17sp"
        android:textStyle="normal" />
    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/iv123"
        android:scaleType="fitCenter"
        android:adjustViewBounds="true"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

Класс для представления данных:

```
public class Phone {
    private String text;
    private int img;

    public Phone(String text, int img) {
        this.text = text;
        this.img = img;
    }

    public String getText() {
        return this.text;
    }

    public void setText(String text) {
        this.text = text;
    }

    public int getImg() {
        return this.img;
    }

    public void setImg(int img) {
        this.img = img;
    }
}
```

И сам адаптер:

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TextView;

import java.util.List;

class DataAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<DataAdapter.ViewHolder> {

    private LayoutInflater inflater;
    private List<Phone> phones;

    DataAdapter(Context context, List<Phone> phones) {
        this.phones = phones;
        this.inflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
    }
    @Override
    public DataAdapter.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {

        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.raz4, parent, false);
        return new ViewHolder(view);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(DataAdapter.ViewHolder holder, int position) {
        Phone phone = phones.get(position);
        holder.nameView.setText(phone.getText());
        holder.imageView.setImageResource(phone.getImg());
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return phones.size();
    }

    public class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        final ImageView imageView;
        final TextView nameView;
        ViewHolder(View view){
            super(view);
            nameView = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.txt123);
            imageView = (ImageView)view.findViewById(R.id.iv123);
        }
    }
}
```

как выглядят изображения при использовании RecyclerView:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения][image: введите сюда описание изображения][image: введите сюда описание изображения]

как я хотел бы, чтобы они выглядят (это при использовании ListView, но я не могу использовать его, т.к. он лагает при прокрутке (ViewHolder пробовал)):

[image: введите сюда описание изображения][image: введите сюда описание изображения][image: введите сюда описание изображения][image: введите сюда описание изображения]

заранее спасибо.

Comment: Напишете подробнее чем отличается ваш результат от ожидаемого. Вообще, по разметке странным выглядит высота ячеек списка, но вряд ли в этом дело. А дело, скорее всего, в том, что RV переиспользует рахметку ячеек по умолчанию, в отличии от LV. Т.е. решением в лоб для одинакового отображения картинок было бы задание для них жёстких размеров. Если нужно что-то более гибкое - напишите что именно - возможно удастся подсказать.

Comment: ЮрийСПб, мне нужно, чтобы картинки были одинаковы по ширине(на всю длину экрана), но при этом не теряли пропорции.

Comment: Попробуйте установить высоту для самой ячейки, и для её TextView и ImageView в `wrap_content` - по идее должно заработать.

Comment: ЮрийСПб, сработало. Покорнейше благодарю.

Answer (score 1):

Вам надо установить высоту для самой ячейки, и для её `TextView` и `ImageView` в `wrap_content`. Так поместится весь текст и картинка. При этом последняя, не имея заранее заданной высоты будет подстраивать оную под ширину, которая задана во весь экран.